# How to automate software installation?

Tags: installation, automation

We make various software at my university and it's now my job to automate the daily build installations.

Does anyone know a tool that would automate the installations? The installations are regular .exe's and they provide the standard install dialog, where you click Next, Next, ..., Finish.

Comment: Can the people building the packages create MSIs instead of EXEs?  It would make deployment a lot easier.

Comment: It's not possible. But they are some kind of installers, maybe install shield. There are actually several different installers.

Comment: Many installers can be automated, but you may need to bug the developers.  They should be able to tell you if those installers support some kind of automated install.

Comment: Yes, please bug them for MSIs.  They were designed for this purpose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to see at [Almeza MultiSet](http://www.almeza.com/)

From [Almeza MultiSet features](http://www.almeza.com/content/view/31/41/) page

> 3) Automatic installation of any software. It is possible to create a
>   CD/DVD that will automatically install any sets of software on
>   multiple computers. For example, after Windows is installed, it is
>   possible to install service packs, drivers, localizations, any
>   software (codecs, audio players, service tools...) and configure them
>   automatically as well.
>
> 4) Creating a bootable disk for simultaneous unattended Windows and
>   software installation. It is possible to create a disk that will
>   install both Windows and a set of software.

Answer (score 2):

**AutoIT**

AutoIT and more specifically the AutoIT Recorder tool can record your actions. You can then convert to .exe and playback your actions on new machines.

**Pros:**

- very simple and easy to learn
- free
- usually works

**Cons:**

- if installer GUI changes, you have to update the recording...might be painful when you manage a lot of software installs

**Batch (.bat) Scripts**

BATch Scripts that feed in command-line arguments for silent install, such as /s or /q for silent/quiet install.

**Pros:**

- basics easy to learn
- work natively on all windows computers

**Cons:**

- not all installers have unattended install built in / working, so it won't always work.
- installers sometimes open additional popups, such as to install other driver software, and these may require user-intervention to agree to install
- batch scripts can be a bit finicky and their syntax unintuitive